# rest of the string after single quote is thrown away

Tags: javascript, php

`CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData()` has a text like  ***This is a' ball .***

i send the following data  to a php page using ajax to store it to a database

```
var data="answer_body="+CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData()+"&userpost_post_id=<?php echo $contents[0]->post_id;?>&users_user_id=<?php echo $userdata->user_id; ?>";
```

But the answer body throws away rest of the text after quote.

```
 $answer=addslashes($_POST['answer_body']);
   echo $answer; // it contains only -----------This is a
```

how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try below Ajax code to send data from client to server

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "Here_Your_Server_Url",
    data: {
        answer_body: encodeURIComponent(CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData()),
        userpost_post_id: "<?php echo $contents[0]->post_id; ?>",
        users_user_id: "<?php echo $userdata->user_id; ?>"
    }
})
```

Try below code in PHP

```
$strAnswerBody = urldecode($_POST['answer_body']);
```